Как минифицировать много файлов .json при сборке проекта на Vite?
Есть проект на Vite+Vue, так же есть много больших статичных файлов справочников, лежащих в  'public/data' c расширением json. Как мне их сжать при сборке, при этом не превращая в js?
Я пытался сделать это через esbuild:
esbuild public/data/*.json --outdir=/dist/public/data/ --allow-overwrite --minify

но он делает .js в котором лежит module export [...] мне так не надо, а нужно просто убрать все pretty-print табы, пробелы и переносы строк.
